# Can I test my Excel formulas as if today was some day in the future?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am building a new dashboard that refreshes on a daily basis. The dashboard includes current month data as well as prior month data. However, I need to try a few different scenarios in terms of dates to ensure that month transitions work with no problem. For example, I would like to know what my formulas would do when it is the first day of the month, and the second day of the month with different conditions such as the 1st day being weekends or holidays, etc, where I won't have any data, which would lead to errors.

I tried fixing formulas, but there were way too many formulas involved and related to each other. Also data is being pulled from SQL server, where I am also using GETDATE().

For example, one of my formulas show

`=YEAR(TODAY()-1)&IF(MONTH(TODAY()-1)<10,0&MONTH(TODAY()-1),MONTH(TODAY()-1))`

to get the year & month (e.g. 201904 for 2019 April). This is one of many formulas that has today() built in

In sum, I am wondering if I can change the date that Excel is reading off. For example, I have a formula with =TODAY() - I want this formula to return some other days I set to, rather than actual date of today.

Comment: Have you tried adding and subtracting to today()?  
today() + 1

Comment: What about having a reference to a range, with the default being `TODAY()-1`? Then you can change the value in that range to test other dates.

Comment: Put `=TODAY()` in a cell that will hold that value.  Change all of your formulas to reference that cell.  For example, if the cell holding `=TODAY()` is A1, then your shown formula would be: `=YEAR(A1-1)&IF(MONTH(A1-1)<10,0&MONTH(A1-1),MONTH(A1-1))`.  Now adjust the cell holding the Today info to whatever date you want to test it out on future dates.  Set it back to `=TODAY()` when testing is completed.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments everyone. I thought about doing it in such way, but was scared because there are way too many formulas and am afraid that ctrl + h won't fix all the formulas I need to fix.

Comment: However, I will give it a try if no other good answers come up. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First place this user defined function in a standard module:

```
Public Function todaz() As Date
    todaz = Evaluate("=today()") + 12
End Function
```

Then in your worksheet, replace all instances of:

```
Today()
```

with:

```
 todaz()
```

[image]

You can change the User defined function to have any date offset you wish.

When you are done testing, change all the `todaz()` back into `Today()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, it looks like what I exactly needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-VBA version:

Have a cell in which you put just `=Today().`  In the worksheet, replace all other instances of Today() with a reference to this cell. For testing, replace the `Today()` with whatever date you like, and when you're done, put the `Today()` back in.

Both this and Gary's Student's version have the advantage of being less volatile - that is, they will run much faster because Today() is one of those functions that recalculates frequently in every place it appears -- and in your case that sounds like a lot.